# C++ -- How to remove the element with such a condition efficient from a STL container?

Tags: c++, stl

Given the following code,

```
struct Student
{
 int score;
}

queue<Student> stdQueue;
```

I want to remove the students from the list if the score of the student is less than the previous one. How to do this efficient?

For example

```
S1(100) <= S2(55) <= S3(200) <= S4(4) <= S6(1000)
```

Get

```
S1 (100) <= S3(200) <= S6(1000)
```

Comment: Impossible with a single std::queue. and I suspect this is homework?

Comment: @Neil: I believe it is possible with a single queue. See my updated answer.

Comment: queue intentionally restricts access to every element except the ones at the ends.  Evidently, you don't want this restriction.  In that case, queue is not the correct data structure for you.  You most likely want a deque.

Comment: "I want to remove the students from the list if the score of the student is less than the previous one." - what is the previous one, if that would be subject to deletion itself? I.e. given `3,1,2`, what is "the previous one" of `2` ? Is that `1`, in which case `2` is kept, or `3`, in which case `2` is removed?

Answer (score 5):

You could write a custom predicate and use `remove_if`. The predicate could be a functor that always stores the `score` of the previous `Student`. Something like this:

```
class ScoreLessThanPrevious {
public:
    ScoreLessThanPrevious() 
     : isFirst(true),
       previousScore(0)
    {}

    bool operator()(const Student & s) {
        if (isFirst) {
            isFirst = false;
            return false;
        }
        else {
            boolean retval = s.score < previousScore;
            previousScore = s.score;
            return retval;
        }
    }
private:
    bool isFirst;
    int previousScore;
};
```

As Neil points out, this is not possible with an `std::queue`. It would, however, work with sequences like a `deque`, `list`, `set` or `vector` (anything that has `begin()` and `end()`).

If you want to do it with a `queue`, do it like this:

1. Remove the first element from the queue (using `pop`).
2. Compare the score to the new first element in the queue (access the first element using `front`).
3. If the score is greater, insert the element again at the back (using `push`), otherwise discard it.
4. Again from 1. until you have the first element at the front again.

To make sure you do not process any element twice, you can do this in a loop that counts up to the original size of the queue.

Comment: @Neil: Right, I just realized that I misread the question. This is not possible with a queue.

Comment: If the container is sorted, presumably?

Comment: Can you insert at the front of a `std::queue`? I thought once you pop it off the front, you can only insert it back at the rear with `push()`?

Comment: @Jason: It does not matter which way. You remove at one end and insert at the other. The rest is an implementation detail ;)

Comment: Can you insert an element at the front of a std::queue? I don't think so.

Comment: I assumed that the question was about manipulating the queue itself - obviously if you can introduce local variables (as your solution requires) you can do anything. So we end up with an algorithm that is hard to understand and possibly very slow. I purely hate these kinds of artificial questions.

Answer (score 1):

A queue is not the right object for this type of thing.  You should use either a priority queue, or a custom queue wrapping a linked-list that would allow you to-do such an operation.  The STL's queue implementation requires that you only access the front and back elements, and accessing any other elements requires the removal of any objects between the front-most element and the element right before the desired element you want from the queue.  So there would be quite a hassle pulling out a bunch of temporary objects, and then pushing them back in, in order to compare the objects and see which ones should be removed.

The priority queue on the other-hand is already sorted internally, so the front and back objects would either be the largest and smallest objects in the queue, or vice-versa.  All other objects in-between would also be sorted.  So as you pop elements off the front of the queue, they would come off in an increasing or decreasing order, depending on what comparison function you've initialized the priority queue with.

You can read-up on the use of a priority queue [here at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/).

Comment: I don't think a priority queue would help here: the task isn't to pull out the elements with the lowest score.  The task is to compare scores of adjactent elements in the order given.

Comment: I see your point, but the OP's question doesn't seem to indicate if the order of students is arbitrary or not ... if the ordering was arbitrary (i.e., there is nothing really determining *why* a student comes before another student, like a name, etc. ... in other words that's just the way the ordering came out, and it might be different the next time around), then why not use a container that would automatically sort the students?

Answer (score 1):

I think the algorithm is something like the following:

1. Get the current size of the queue, call it N.
2. pop 1 element, call it Prev
3. push Prev
4. repeat N-1 times

   1. pop element, call it Cur
   2. if Cur >= Prev, push Cur
   3. set Prev = Cur

Basically rotate through the entire queue, but only push back the elements that compare favorably with the preceeding one.